# Проверка на совпадение в хранимой процедуре MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

В БД есть таблица (my_table) с двумя столбцами ID и NAME. Хочу сделать процедуру для INSERT/UPDATE. Если совпадение найдено - изменяем значение, если нет - добавляем.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ins_upd (in x int(10), in y varchar(20))
begin
if (x IN (SELECT ID FROM my_table) then 
UPDATE my_table SET ID=x, NAME=y; 
else
INSERT INTO my_table values (x, y);
end if;
end//
```

ругается на синтаксис, подскажите что не так?

Comment: Добрый человек подсказал такую штуку, как "ON DUBLICATE KEY". Но у меня всё равно ругается на синтаксис в этой строке:
INSERT INTO my_table values(x, y) ON DUBLICATE KEY UPDATE ID=x, NAME=y;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо if else подсказали удобную штуку(спасибо Akina) - ON DUPLICATE KEY. С помощью неё (и кучи попыток) получилась такая хранимая процедура:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ins_upd (new_ID int(10), new_NAME varchar(20))
INSERT INTO my_table (ID, NAME) VALUES (new_ID, new_NAME)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NAME=new_NAME;
//
```

Долго не получалось из за того, что писал DUBLICATE вместо DUPLICATE